# Unable to search "c++" on Google Search

Tags: search

I recently installed the Disconnect Search (https://disconnect.me/) and now I am unable to search "c++". For example, when I search "c++ through examples", I get results for "c through examples". Can anyone explain this? It seems like the "++" are now replaced by two invisible characters after "c" in the search bar. I am using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04.I am sorry if I am asking this on the wrong platform. Please refer me to the right one in that case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use Google

Comment: where should this be put up then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you cant do it, but 'cpp' is a synonym for c++ in google so try that, or heres a link:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2B%2B+through+examples&oq=c%2B%2B+through&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.6492j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yes, using "cpp" or "c plus plus" is a get around which I tried almost instantly. But not sure why this is happening.
And the funny thing is that even the link provided by you is behaving the same way, I am getting results for "c  through examples".